# How to use this intercom?

Tags: old-house

My home has this intercom [image: intercom] (I was told they are intercom) in bedrooms. I am not sure how to use it, and I can not find the manual or model number.
My question is what it is used for and how to use this?

Comment: you need to have a person at each end, then start experimenting

Comment: The power for this might also be plugged into the wall in some strange place, I found one plugged under a sink once.

Comment: It is use for talking to people in other rooms.  It saves Jim-Bob from yelling for his beer.  If system is still working, you press talk button to talk to person.  It is probably a wired system and might not work anymore, broken wires, parts wear out over time.

Comment: Nutone was (is?) a big name in intercoms, a quick Google found lots of panels that look similar.  Perhaps that would get you a manual similar enough to be useful.

Comment: Appliance usage is off topic on this site. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: do you hear background noise when pressing  one of the listen buttons? If not, you need to have the wiring checked out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because appliance usage is off-topic. Here's what's [on-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without even bothering to look for a manual, and assuming it's powered/functional still, UX looks clear enough:

Punch the **monitor** button to enable, **private** to disable each unit.

Punch the **"listen"** button to listen to **"door"** and/or **"patio"** (which may be standard labels *not matching the actual description of the place your units are* - you'll have to figure that out) and the respective **"talk"** button to talk to them.

At a location you wish to talk from, you press the **talk**, and if another unit has your unit's **listen** button pressed, they should hear you. If either unit is **"Private"** that should not work.

There may be slight detail differences, but that would be the general idea of this antique. *i.e.* more than one unit may share a button (perhaps all inside units are as one?)